# Hibernate and spring data repository, object incomplete after save or update

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

After saving or updating an object of this entity through a spring data repository (which extends CrudRepository):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="finance_data")
public class FinanceData implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="asset_type", nullable=false)
private AssetType assetType;
```

It only returns the `Id` for the `assetType` property. This is forcing us to execute a findOne after the update to get the full information.

How can I tell to hibernate to return the whole object?

Comment: can you add the save / update code sample and how later try to retrieve the assettype?

Comment: It is a spring-data-jpa repository, I do not have any code more than this:

@Repository
public interface FinanceDataRepository extends CrudRepository<FinanceData, Integer>{

}

Comment: you said you are forcing the findOne to get the data.. so there is some code around the jpa call

Comment: Not at all, The "findOne" (as well as save, delete ...) method is extended from the interface CrudRepository

Comment: its just not 100% clear what your aiming at.. showing how you create the enttiy, save / upadte it.. and how you try to retrieve its content

Comment: Hibernate doesn't need to return anything; the full AssetType object needs to be already set upon saving. I can only imagine that there is something like a trigger involved here which is responsible for setting the assetType?

Comment: @Gimby I understand your point. When I try to save a new FinanceData record, I only set the refenrece id for property AssetType because they exists before the FinanceData is recorded. And this is what the save method retunrs. My question is if there is a way to tell Hibernate something like "hey, after save or update, excute a select and bring back the whole entity"? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It only returns the Id for the `assetType` property.

This is because all the other fields are set to `null` by your own action (as described in the comments):

> When I try to save a new FinanceData record, I only set the reference id for property `AssetType` because they exist before the `FinanceData` is recorded.

Instead of just setting the `Id` and thereby overwriting all other fields, load the `AssetType` by `Id` and use that.